# JavaScript Rock Paper Scissors console game Errors

Tags: javascript, project

**Beginner JavaScript console Rock Paper Scissors project.**

For some reason the only outcome I am getting is "Error. Only enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors." I don't know I'm just stumped. I am also a complete beginner.

Before this error I had it half working, now its just broken. Any help would be nice.

```js
const playerSelection = prompt('Rock, Paper, Scissors?').toLowerCase();
const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
const computerSelection = computerPlay();


function caseInsensitive(playerSelection) {
  return playerSelection.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + playerSelection.slice(1);
}
console.log(caseInsensitive(playerSelection))

function computerPlay() {
  if (randomInt === 0) {
    return 'Rock';
  } else if (randomInt === 1) {
    return 'Paper';
  } else {
    return 'Scissors'
  }
}
console.log(computerPlay())

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    return (`You win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`)
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return (`You win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`)
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return (`You win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`)
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return (`You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`)
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return (`You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`)
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    return (`You lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`)
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return (`It's a tie, Refresh to play again!`)
  } else {
    return (`Error. Only enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors`)
  }
}

console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: You're using `toLowerCase()` on the user's selection, but then you're comparing it with strings that have uppercase letters.

Comment: Bunch of issues. Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/8ug6at1p/

Comment: @ChrisSharp What are you talking about? It's just a prompt string, not a word you select.

Comment: So, it looks like you need to research how to debug your code.  You may need to inspect each and every line to verify that you're getting the result you expect -- that will help you locate the errors & problems.  Make use of F12 Developer Tools Console tab